# Extjs domquery issue

Tags: extjs

I have a simple grid with one of the columns being a 'download' link placed like this:

```
{
    header: 'Config files',
    width: 130,
    sortable: false,
    fixed: true,
    renderer: function() {
        return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="downloadCfg">Download</a>';
    }
}
```

This is in the view. Now moving on to the controller I placed a listener on the grid to catch whenever the link is clicked:

```
init : function() {
    this.control({
        'accountFiles a[class=downloadCfg]': {
            click: function () {
                alert('test');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Very basic but it doesnt work. Can it be because the link is created via the 'renderer' function of the grid? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Romeo

This is how you can grab whether the Download link is clicked or not:

```
'accountFiles': {
            itemclick: function( thisView, record, item, index, e, eOpts ) {
                var t = e.getTarget('.downloadCfg');

                if (!Ext.isEmpty(t))
                    alert('Download clicked!!');
                else
                    alert('Other item clicked!!');
            }
        }
```

Once you have identified that the Download link is clicked, you have the record containing the complete record representing the row.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to fix this issue, but I know another solution.

Create method in GridPanel:

```
doDownload: function(recordId) {
    var record = this.getStore().data.get(recordId);
    // do something
}
```

Then create change renderer to:

```
renderer: function(value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
    return '<a href="#" onclick="Ext.getCmp(Ext.get(this).parent(\'.x-grid\').id).doDownload(\'' + store.data.getKey(record) + '\')">Download</a>';
}
```

Action in `onclick` handler tries to find grid using dom classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
accountFiles a[class=downloadCfg]
```

will select all descendant of **accountFiles** tag which have **a** tag. And filter them by class attribute.

It seems to me that you confused it with ComponentQuery syntax where you select by component id not by tag.

Comment: no it's not confused. I want to grab the action when a link with the class of 'downloadCfg' is clicked. That link is rendered in a grid on each row is presented.